# How to remove set from portage

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I was dealing with a lot of blocks of Qt5.

```
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qtgui-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qtgui-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qtsql-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qtsql-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qtcore-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qtcore-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qtopengl-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qtopengl-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qt3support-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qt3support-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qtscript-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qtscript-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qttest-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qttest-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qtphonon-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qtphonon-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qtxmlpatterns-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qtxmlpatterns-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qtwebkit-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qtwebkit-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qtdbus-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qtdbus-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)
[blocks B      ] <dev-qt/qtsvg-4.8.6:4 ("<dev-qt/qtsvg-4.8.6:4" is blocking dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102)

  (dev-qt/qtchooser-0_p20150102:0/0::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge) pulled in by
    dev-qt/qtchooser required by (dev-qt/qtpositioning-5.4.0:5/5::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
    dev-qt/qtchooser required by (dev-qt/qtgraphicaleffects-5.4.0:5/5::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
    dev-qt/qtchooser required by (dev-qt/qtcore-5.4.0:5/5::gentoo, ebuild scheduled for merge)
  ...
```

But I had no qt5 installed (probably removed one by one - I was trying to solve it some time ago):

```
# equery list qt*-5*
 * Searching for qt*-5* ...
!!! No installed packages matching 'qt*-5*'
```

I have even added `-qt5` to USE flags.

I remember I used some qt5 sets via `emerge --ask @qt5-essentials @qt5-addons` and listing sets confirms that.

```
# emerge --list-sets
...
qt5-addons
qt5-essentials
qt5-tools
```

but I can not find any way how to get rid of them - no emerge options. And custom sets directory doesn't exists:

```
# ls /etc/portage/sets/
ls: cannot access /etc/portage/sets/: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no command.

Checking `/var/lib/portage/world_sets` reveals the truth :)

```
# cat  /var/lib/portage/world_sets
@qt5-addons
@qt5-essentials
```

After removing, full update (@world) doesn't complain anymore.

Next time check first `man emerge`, sets are mentioned at start:

```
set    A set is a convenient shorthand for a large group of packages. Three sets are currently always available: selected, system and world. selected contains the user-selected  "world"  packages  that  are
       listed  in /var/lib/portage/world, and nested sets that may be listed in /var/lib/portage/world_sets. system refers to a set of packages deemed necessary for your system to run properly. world encom‐
       passes both the selected and system sets. [See FILES below for more information.] Other sets can exist depending on the current  configuration.  The  default  set  configuration  is  located  in  the
       /usr/share/portage/config/sets  directory.   User  sets  may  be  created  by placing files in the /etc/portage/sets/ directory (see portage(5)). Note that a set is generally used in conjunction with
       --update. When used as arguments to emerge sets have to be prefixed with @ to be recognized. Use the --list-sets action to display a list of available package sets.
```